# Manually sharing a record with a community user shares the record with all internal users

Tags: apex, community, sharing, apex-managed-sharing

When sharing a record with a community user manually (thru apex) - the record becomes visible to AllInternalUsers.

Is this intended? How can I circumvent this issue?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include details about the OWD and any sharing rules for internal users, and also the relevant sections of your Apex code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that all community users have as hierarchy all standard users who have access to them.

To opt out of this mechanism you can disable access using hierarchies:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_controlling_access_using_hierarchies.htm&language=en_US&type=5